# c# use one variable value to set a second from a fixed list

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, lookup-tables

I'm parsing a CSV file in a c# .net windows form app, taking each line into a class I've created, however I only need access to some of the columns AND the files being taken in are not standardized.  That is to say, number of fields present could be different and the columns could appear in any column.

CSV Example 1:

```
Position, LOCATION, TAG, NAME, STANDARD, EFFICIENCY, IN USE,,
1, AFT-D3, P-D3101A, EQUIPMENT 1, A, 3, TRUE
2, AFT-D3, P-D3103A, EQUIPMENT 2, B, 3, FALSE
3, AFT-D3, P-D2301A, EQUIPMENT 3, A, 3, TRUE
...
```

CSV Example 2:

```
Position, TAG, STANDARD, NAME, EFFICIENCY, LOCATION, BACKUP, TESTED,,
1, P-D3101A, A, EQUIPMENT 1, 3, AFT-D3, FALSE, TRUE
2, P-D3103A, A, EQUIPMENT 2, 3, AFT-D3, TRUE, FALSE
3, P-D2301A, A, EQUIPMENT 3, 3, AFT-D3, FALSE, TRUE
...
```

As you can see, I will never know the format of the file I have to analyse, the only thing I know for sure is that it will always contain the few columns that I need.

My solution to this was to ask the user to enter the columns required and set as strings, the using their entry convert that to a corresponding integer that i could then use as a location.

```
string standardInpt = "";
string nameInpt = "";
string efficiencyInpt = "";
```

user would then enter a value from A to ZZ.

```
int standardLocation = 0;
int nameLocation = 0;
int efficiencyLocation = 0;
```

when the form is submitted. the ints get their final value by running through an if else... statement:

```
if(standard == "A")
{
  standardLocation = 0;
}
else if(standard == "B") 
{
  standardLocation = 1;
}
...
```

etc running all the way to if VAR1 == ZZ and then the code is repeated for VAR2 and for VAR3 etc..

My class would partially look like:

```
class Equipment
{
  public string Standard { get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Efficiency { get; set; }

  static Equipment FromLine(string line)
  {
     var data = line.split(',');

     return new Equipment()
     {
      Standard = data[standardLocation],
      Name = [nameLocation],
      Efficiency = int.Parse(data[efficiencyLocation]),
     };
   }
}
```

I've got more code in there but i think this highlights where I would use the variables to set the indexes.

I'm very new to this and I'm hoping there has got to be a significantly better way to achieve this without having to write so much potentially excessive, repetitive If Else logic. I'm thinking some kind of lookup table maybe, but i cant figure out how to implement this, any pointers on where i could look?

Comment: I think I know what you mean but could you give us two or three examples of input files? Just the first two or three rows for each so we can see the schemas and how they differ?

Comment: I actually realise that i've explained this pretty poorly,  going to do solid edit, will include example file.

Comment: If they always have the same name, parse the header line in the file and look for `STANDARD`, `NAME`, and `EFFICIENCY` and store the positions. Then use them to read from the right place, no need to ask the user about where the fields are.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it automatic by finding the indexes of the columns in the header, and then use them to read the values from the correct place from the rest of the lines:

```
class EquipmentParser {
    public IList<Equipment> Parse(string[] input) {
        var result = new List<Equipment>();

        var header = input[0].Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim().ToLower()).ToList();
        var standardPosition = GetIndexOf(header, "std", "standard", "st");
        var namePosition = GetIndexOf(header, "name", "nm");
        var efficiencyPosition = GetIndexOf(header, "efficiency", "eff");

        foreach (var s in input.Skip(1)) {
            var line = s.Split(',');
            result.Add(new Equipment {
                Standard = line[standardPosition].Trim(),
                Name = line[namePosition].Trim(),
                Efficiency = int.Parse(line[efficiencyPosition])
            });
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int GetIndexOf(IList<string> input, params string[] needles) {
        return Array.FindIndex(input.ToArray(), needles.Contains);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't guarantee the CSV author used the recommended header title, however if i could say guarantee they used any one of a small sample e.g (STANDARD, standard, Standard, ST, St, st, STND, Stnd, stnd) etc, could i potentially use some implementation of OR?

Comment: Sure, I also made the header lowercase so you only have to add `standard` to your list of matches and not `STANDARD, standard, Standard `.

Comment: You really should think about putting a foot down at some point and force the authors to consistent inputs. Another option to keep the parsing code clean is, run a formatter over the file that changes only the headers from whatever input values you get to the ones you need and only _then_ run your parser over it.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel : interestingly enough that's exactly what I requested they do. Files will be now formatted for header consistency before being parsed.

Comment: I'll give you +1 just because you tackled the root cause. Good job!

Comment: @JLe Reading through this it seems to do exactly what I need, but this is taking in an Array  and I cant for the life of me figure out how to get my CSV through it.  Previously, user saves the filepath as a string `referenceFile` however with your example I cant use that as input.  Not looking for someone to code it for me, just a nod in the right direction.

Comment: The direction is to use the File class in System.IO to read all the lines in the file. File.ReadAllLines().

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reflection and attribute.

Write your samples in `,`separated into `DisplayName` Attribute.

First call `GetIndexes` with the csv header string as parameter to get the mapping dictionary of class properties and csv fields.

Then call `FromLine` with each line and the mapping dictionary you just got.

```
class Equipment
{
    [DisplayName("STND, STANDARD, ST")]
    public string Standard { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("EFFICIENCY, EFFI")]
    public int Efficiency { get; set; }
    // You can add any other property

    public static Equipment FromLine(string line, Dictionary<PropertyInfo, int> map)
    {
        var data = line.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray();
        var ret = new Equipment();
        Type type = typeof(Equipment);
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            int index = map[property];
            property.SetValue(ret, Convert.ChangeType(data[index],
                property.PropertyType));
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static Dictionary<PropertyInfo, int> GetIndexes(string headers)
    {
        var headerArray = headers.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray();
        Type type = typeof(Equipment);
        var ret = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, int>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var fieldNames = property.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()
                .DisplayName.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < headerArray.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (!fieldNames.Contains(headerArray[i])) continue;
                ret[property] = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if helpful:

```
    public int GetIndex(string input)
    {
        input = input.ToUpper();
        char low = input[input.Length - 1];
        char? high = input.Length == 2 ? input[0] : (char?)null;
        int indexLow = low - 'A';
        int? indexHigh = high.HasValue ? high.Value - 'A' : (int?)null;
        return (indexHigh.HasValue ? (indexHigh.Value + 1) * 26 : 0) + indexLow;
    }
```

Comment: convert a,b,c,d,e..ZZ to interger

Answer (score -1):

You can use ASCII code for that , so no need to add if else every time
ex.

```
    byte[] ASCIIValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(standard);
    standardLocation  = ASCIIValues[0]-65;
```

Comment: this code work only for one character in standard string Variable

Comment: He said that the values could be `A` to `ZZ`, so then this wouldn't work.